# Doubt on page 24 of Klenke's Probability Theory.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In the following example, page 24 2nd edition of Klenke's prob. book, he states that we need only to check that the set function is only $\sigma$-subadditive.[image]

However, the part of the assumptions of theorem 1.53(uniqueness of an extension of a set function to a measure from a semi-ring) are also that the set function is additive, $\sigma$-finite, etc. Why is it not necessary to check the remaining assumptions of the theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other things to check are that $\mu$ is non-negative and finitely additive, that $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$ and that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

The author might have thought those were implied directly from the definition, in part because those assumptions were checked in the $n = 1$ case in Example 1.30 viii.

Comment: Thanks Brendan.